# Outputting JSON object by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{"cat1":"m1","cat2":["d1","d2","d3"],"cat3":["m1","m2","m3","m4"]}
```

In Javascript, I'm trying to output the strings by category (cat1-3), this is my code so far.

```
$.post(loadUrl, function(data){

    $("#result").html("<p>Cat1: " + data.cat1 + "</p><p>Cat2: " + data.cat2 + "</p>");

});
```

I would normally not use JSON (Usually JSTL) but since I want to learn AJAX, I want to try output the cat1-3 values by the key, which I keep getting "undefined".

I was using this as a guide to get the values: http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/01/27/json-javascript-tutorial/

Comment: @Felix Kling - yep you were right, I had to parse the JSON string. `var item = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`

Answer (score 3):

Try below script

```
va response =  {"cat1":"m1","cat2":["d1","d2","d3"],"cat3":["m1","m2","m3","m4"]}

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

alert(obj.cat1);
```

it will return m1

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = JSON.parse("{\"cat1\":\"m1\",\"cat2\":[\"d1\",\"d2\",\"d3\"],\"cat3\":[\"m1\",\"m2\",\"m3\",\"m4\"]}"); 

for(key in a)
{
     alert(key);
     alert(a[key]); 
}
```

Comment: Why not '{"cat1":"m1","cat2":["d1","d2","d3"],"cat3":["m1","m2","m3","m4"]}' instead of escaping every single quotation mark